# Same data in 3 different SapScript Elements

Tags: abap

I have 3 Elements that is calling from F111 which are 610-1,610-2 & 610-3.
I want to pass in these 3 elements the same data.
Is it possible to do it in another way other than writing the same data 3 times?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your current code? ("writing the same data 3 times") Is your question specific to the transaction code `F111` or does it apply to any SapScript form?

Comment: I do not want to change the program which depending of the setup of Payment Method which is between 0 to 9. So if the payment method is 1 calls the element 610-1, if the payment method is 2 the element is 610-2 etc. The business want to be print the same thing. So for each element 610-1, 610-2, ....610-9 i must put the same lines. That's why I am asking if I can do sth else except of writing 9 times 15 lines of the same sapscript code, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know F111, but as far as I can understand, you say there is a standard driver program whose algorithm selects from one SAPscript window which element to print (something like `Case paym. When '1'. Call function 'WRITE_FORM' exporting element = '610-1'`, etc.), and you have substituted the standard SAPscript form with a custom one. In your custom SAPscript form, you want every element to contain 15 lines of the same text/code, but you don't want to repeat it.

So, to include the same text several times, you may create a Standard Text (for instance) via the transaction code `SO10`, and use the SAPscript command [**`INCLUDE`**](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/SAP_NETWEAVER_700/7.0.36/en-US?q=Including%20Other%20Texts:%20INCLUDE):

```
/E 610-1
/: INCLUDE ZF111-610
/E 610-2
/: INCLUDE ZF111-610 
...
```

Comment: Sandra thanks a lot. Most probably this is what I want to do. I will implement it sometime in the day (because I am in another customer) and I will tell you. Thanks again

Comment: Sandra, I test it and this is what I want. This BEST PRACTICE in writing a program. LESS Code, More Efficient and much more easy in maintenance. Thanks a lot.